# Can't Write to Firebase, No Errors

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason, every time I try to write to my Firebase Database nothing appears in the database and no errors are thrown. After a user makes an account, I check whether the user is in the database, and if not take them to a setup page where they choose a display name and account type (student or teacher). Then I enter that into the database. I have no problem reading from the database, and I can write to it from my python backend, but I am unable to successfully write anything from the javascript frontend. Here is my code

```
              <script>
              function teacherType (){
                  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            var database = firebase.database();
                var name = document.getElementById("displayName").value;
                 firebase.database().ref('/users/teachers/' + uid).set({"displayName":name}).then(window.location.replace("/teacherDashboard"));

              };
              function studentType (){
                  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
            var database = firebase.database();
                var name = document.getElementById("displayName").value;
                 firebase.database().ref('/users/students/' + uid).set({"displayName":name}).then(window.location.replace("/studentDashboard"));
              };
          </script>
          <section id="main">
          <div class="content-section text-center" id="accountType">
                        <p>Add your Display Name Below</p>
     <input id="displayName"/>
              <p>Are you a student or a teacher?</p>
              <span>                <a onclick="studentType()" href="#" 
        class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><font face="sans-serif">Student</font>
                    </a></span>
<span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><font face="sans-serif" onclick="teacherType()">Teacher</font>
              </a></span>
              </div>


          </section>
```

Sorry for the bad formatting. I tested to see that uid and name were defined, so I don't think that is the problem. Nevertheless, nothing appears in the firebase database, and the site goes to `/teacherDashboard` or `/studentDashboard` accordingly. I'm not sure what I'm missing...

Comment: Are you sure you have a correct value for uid? What do you get if you do `function teacherType (){
                  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; console.log(uid); ....`

Comment: Last time I did it, it printed a correct uid that I checked in the firebase users console. Tt shouldn't really matter if it is a valid uid, though, right? I'm not quite sure how `db.reference()` works, but I gather that it will create an entry with uid even if one doesn't exist, so no matter what uid is it should at least create some database entry.

Comment: No reason why it wouldn't be working, you are right on the bit that it should create an entry if it does not exist. Try using the set function without any variables and see if anything gets created then.

Comment: well, derp. I tried the things both of you mentioned and it worked perfectly fine, but the main function decided not to work for another half an hour, until it spontaneously did. Not really sure why... I didn't change anything...                            UPDATE: I did change something unrelated that I didn't think would make a difference or was worth mentioning. I got rid of the `window.location.replace(...)` bit. I think that part is cutting off the db request before it finishes. Any ideas on how to fix that?